# Как правильно добавить картинку в android приложение что бы она выглядела адекватно на всех экранах?

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

Я добавляю картинку через VectorAsset и получаю ошибку:"The image may be incomplete: ERROR line 3  is not supported".
Хотя открываю svg этот файл, который пытаюсь запихать и он выглядит абсолютно адекватно.
Если же добавляю просто png то он размазывается на разных dpi, что логично.
Как правильно добавить картинку в android-приложение что бы её можно было растягивать без потери качества?(главный логотип приложения).

Comment: Исправить svg-файл.

Comment: Перейдите по ссылке, нажмите "Import" -> "SVG" и выберете свой SVG файл, после "Export" -> "Vector Drawable". https://shapeshifter.design/

Comment: проигнорируйте эту ошибку